# How to generate graphs using pylint pyreverse in Spyder IDE

Tags: python, graph, spyder, pylint, pyreverse

I am using pylint in spyder notebook to perform static code analysis. I came to know that pyreverse is included into pylint to generate graphs. Can someone help me to understand how to invoke pyreserve and use it to generate code analysis graphs.